# mongoose.connect() will no longer take in a variable in place of a string

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, mongoose, uri

I'm getting this error:

`The 'uri' parameter to 'openUri()' must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to 'mongoose.connect()' or 'mongoose.createConnection()' is a string.`

This is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = process.env.MONGOURI;

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });

        console.log('MongoDB Connected...');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        // Exit process with failure
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

This had always worked before, but no it seems to no longer accept variables for strings (even though hovering over the 'db' in that first parameter reveals it is identified as a string.

When I replace the variable with a proper string of the full mongoURI it works. Server runs and my database connects.

Not sure why the previous approach is no longer working for me. I must've overlooked something. Anyone have any insight?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check if your env variable `MONGOURI` is correctly set.

Comment: have you created environment file `.env` and check the connection string variable `MONGOURI` in it.